# How can I make test and testOnly tasks both depend on a new task?

Tags: sbt

I have written a new task that I want to run before tests are executed. There are two tasks that can be used to run tests `test` and `testOnly` and so I have made both of these depend on my new task like so,

```
(testOnly in Test) <<= (testOnly in Test) dependsOn startIntegrationTestServerIfNotAlreadyRunning
(test in Test) <<= (test in Test) dependsOn startIntegrationTestServerIfNotAlreadyRunning
```

It works but it feels a bit verbose. Is there a single task that I could make depend on my task that would achieve the same ends?

Comment: Use inspect tree test, and similarly testOnly, find a common intersection and place your dependency there